# What is the distribution of the ratio of two independent variables, each subject to Rayleigh distribution with different standard deviation?

Tags: ratio, rayleigh-distribution

I am trying to find what is the distribution of the ratio of two independent Rayleigh random variables, each of which has different standard deviation.

Comment: Hello complexfilter, is this a homework problem from a school assignment?  You can find some help [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

Comment: No. It is related to a project I am working on. I think this paper tells me the answer: https://epublications.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1190&context=mscs_fac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia indicates that the square of a single rayleigh random variable $R$ with parameter $\sigma$ follows a gamma distribution with shape parameter 1 and scale parameter $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$, $R^2\sim \text{Gamma}(1,\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})$.  Note that $\sigma$ is not the standard deviation.  Then the ratio of the square of two Rayleigh random variables can be expressed as the ratio of two chi-square random variables.  Under the hypothesis that the two $\sigma$ parameters are equal, this ratio would follow an $F$-distribution.  Under the hypothesis that the two $\sigma$ parameters are different, the ratio would follow a non-central $F$-distribution.  Your original question asked for the distribution of the ratio, which would be the distribution of a square rooted random variable that follows an $F$-distribution.  Let me know if I have made any mistakes or if you need more clarity.